# "Apply only permissions changes on sub-elements" or "Apply permissions changes only on sub elements"?

Tags: sentence-structure

In a web-application where you can manage and organize resources (eg.: files, events, discussions/chat and so on) inside a certain structure (lets say folder structure) and you can grant permissions to users on these resources.

If you want to inform the user that he is going to make a permissions change **only** on the sub-folders and **not** in the folder he's currently working, is it more correct to say :

> Apply only permissions changes on sub-folders

or

> Apply permissions changes only on sub-folders

I'm Italian and for me the second sentence ( position of **only** ) looks more correct/suitable for what I'm trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these permissions changes will be made **only** on the sub-folders as you mentioned in your question, I think it is more correct to say:

> Apply permissions changes only on sub-folders